# Modal popup send values to parent window for dialog opened using SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, promoted-links

Sharepoint promoted links webpart open in dialog opens the popup using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)`. I am closing the pop using  `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)` . But I want to redirect the parent window to a url which is to be sent from modal popup. But promoted links doesn't send object to return value in `dialogReturnValueCallback`. Is there a way where we can still redirect the parent page to a url?